# Debian Web server with dual ethernet

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ethernet

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdxyM.jpg)

Hi all,

I have a web server (debian 9) and 2 internet line, I want to public website on both lines to do HA, I already configured nat on both FW. Tested for each line alone is ok but I can't connect to both line at same time. That mean if both ethernet is up, I only can access to 3.4.5.6 (server's default gateway), 1.2.3.4 still pingable but can't access. I still can access from any IP in 192.168.2.0/24 at that time.

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0 as default

Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: firewall is disabled, if I use only 1 ens192 or 224, It works fine. 3.4.5.6 and 1.2.3.4 is my public IP (to publish web to internet)

Comment: Add results of `ip route show` to question, and also read the answer from madcap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think want you want is Source Based Routing. I found a one example http://wiki.wlug.org.nz/SourceBasedRouting